# the use of した to modify nouns

Tags: relative-clauses, tense

Recently I came across this phrase:

> 血液型に関係したことって、日本では、すごく人気がある

Why is 関係した in the past and not in the present? In this case, is there any difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the English verb *relate*.  We commonly use the past-tense form as an adjective.

> 血液型に**関係した**こと
>     ↓
> things **related** to blood type

This is one of those uncommon areas where the Japanese and English grammar line up -- likely due to the shared underlying nature of the concept.  The relation itself is something that is *already established*, so we use the past tense (or completed aspect, if we're being more specific).

Comment: This "related" is the *past participle* of "relate", not the past tense form.  The two forms happen to coincide for most verbs, but the difference surfaces for some irregular verbs (e.g., "the answer *written* by X" is not "the answer wrote by X").

Comment: @L.F., yes, but ultimately not terribly relevant -- the key is that both forms of English verbs are past, expressing a completed aspect with relation to the action of the verb (hence my parenthetical comment).  For purposes of cross-linguistic comparison, it's also worth noting that Japanese has no distinction between past tense and past participle.